# While Importing UMLS data into Neo4J there is a error in uploading CODEs file

Tags: neo4j, importerror

I tried to upload the data below (which is in .csv format) into Neo4J local and also into AuraDb:

[image: Snippet of .csv file]

But only the first 2 nodes with a given CodeID are imported:

```
0, COSTAR, NOCODE
1, NCBI, 137507
```

I tried to add the index column, then all the nodes were uploading. But when linking relationships using other files there is mismatching.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [neo4j-admin import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/neo4j-admin-import/) command, you are using it incorrectly.

The `:ID` field in a column header is supposed to indicate that the values in the column are unique, but your .csv file uses nonunique values.

You should be able to remove the `:ID` part of the header, and that may allow all the nodes to be created. *But* if you do that, you would not be able to import relationships, since that expects unique identifiers for the nodes that are to be linked (see [the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/neo4j-admin-import/#import-tool-header-format-nodes)).

The fix for this issue depends on your specific use case.

Comment: Hi cybersam, I tried all the import methods which were referred in the docs but I am not able to import both nodes and relations. Is there any other thing which I can do to import both nodes and relations.

Comment: [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/) is a very flexible way to load nodes and relationships, since you can use the full power of Cypher.